# php query, price change depending on hour of the day

Tags: php

i have the following table with values from a sql query:
[image]

now depending on the hour of the day, i want to be able to change the values.
for example, its late in the afternoon, i choose the option 3 dagen EUR 20.00. Since right now this day is already almost over, i should pay a smaller amount for 1 dag (example EUR 4), and then the price for 2 dagen EUR 14.00, so at this hour of the day the box 3 dagen should show EUR 18.00

So i know how to get the current hour, but how can i change my query to reflect this?
This is the query i used to get this table:

```
<?php
        echo "<h2>".$lang['pagina3_dagen']."</h2>";

        $number=="0";
        echo "<table class='prijs'>";
        echo "<tr>";

            $query="SELECT * FROM $tabel WHERE fietstype='$fietskeuze'";
            $result=mysql_query($query) or die ("Ophalen prijzen mislukt: ".mysql_error());

            while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $days=$row[days];
            $price=$row[price];

            if ($days=="1") $writeday=$lang['pagina3_1dag'];
            if ($days >="2") $writeday=$lang['pagina3_meerderedagen'];

            echo "<td class='prijs'><h2><a href='framemaat.php?lang=".$_SESSION['lang']."&naam=".$naam."&postcodehuisnummer=".$postcodehuisnummer."&fietskeuze=".$fietskeuze."&opties=".$opties."&optieid=".$optieid."&days=".$days."'>".$days." ".$writeday."<br>EUR ".$price."</a><br>";
            $number++;
            if ($number=="5") {echo "<tr>"; $number="0";}   
            } 
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table>"; 
?>
```

i was thinking in pseudo-like code something like this:

```
$currenthour = date("H", time());
if (($currenthour >="13") && ($currenthour <"15"))
    {
    $pricedag1=($pricedag1-3eurodiscount);
    price in table result for 3 dagen=($pricedag1+$priceofdag2)
    }
```

but how to get the price of the previous day? so the second to last value coming from the query?

Comment: Why don't you just retrieve the prices as-is from the database and adjust them once you have the "real" prices (e.g., while looping through the results)?

Comment: Be careful. The time where? At the server? At the user's location? How do you know where the user is?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand the details of your table, but here's a shot:

Why not have a separate table that holds discounts for your products (dagens?) ?   This way, you can query your products and join it against the discount table.

```
// you can decide the data type
CREATE TABLE Discounts (discount_id, product_id, start, end, discount);
```

then you could left join with your product table

```
    SELECT p.*, d.discount 
      FROM products p
 LEFT JOIN discounts d ON d.product_id = p.product_id 
       AND start <= ? AND end >= ?;
```

So after you've received your result set, you can check whether discount is empty or not.  If it's not, apply the necessary discount.

```
if (!empty($row['discount']) {
   $price = $price - $row['discount'];
}
```

Of course, you could take it a step further and determine types of discounts - percentage off, dollar off, etc.